# Read S3 Files That Meet Last Modified Window Into DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, boto3

I have an S3 bucket with objects where the Last Modified ranges from very old to current.  I need to be able to find the files with a last modified stamp within a window, and then read those files (which are JSON) into some sort of Data Frame (pandas, spark, etc.).

I have attempted to gather the files, read them in individually and append via the following code but it is painfully slow:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=region)

#Gather all keys that have a modified stamp between max_previous_data_extracted_timestamp and start_time_proper
s3 = session.resource('s3', region_name=region)
bucket = s3.Bucket(args.sourceBucket)
app_body = []
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    obj_datetime = obj.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=None)
    if args.accountId + '/Patient' in obj.key and obj_datetime > max_previous_data_extracted_timestamp_datetime and obj_datetime <= start_time_datetime:
        obj_df = pd.read_csv(obj.get()['Body'])
        app_body.append(obj_df)

merged_dataframe = pd.concat(app_body)
```

The logic is functional in that I only get objects that have been modified within the window, however, the next part where it gets the body and appends to the list runs for 30-45 minutes on ~10K files.  There has to be a better way to do this that I am just not thinking of.

Comment: What is the structure within the S3 bucket? Is there a patter in file names? How many files do you have?

Comment: The structure is bucket/account_identifier/Patient/patient_identifier, where the identifiers are UUID style strings and the patient_identifier is the file name, a JSON file.  There are approximately 8K files in the static directory that I am pulling from, specifying an account_identifier.

Comment: an example: s3://bucket_name/123g9999-c424-4662-86c8-f99cae5bb51e/Patient/3748295d-3b78-4927-b4fc-4b33ad7gev8a

Comment: In the JSON, are objects `new line` separated (one JSON object per line)?

Comment: No, each file is a single JSON object, placed on a single line.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what a profiler returns on this one, would be nice to see where the bottleneck is to determine a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark is a way to go on this one.

When talking to S3 bucket with a large number of files, we always need to keep in mind that listing all objects in a bucket is expensive since it returns 1000 object at a time and a pointer to fetch the next set. This makes it very hard to parallelise unless you know the structure and use it to optimize those calls.

I'm sorry if the code doesn't work, I use scala but this should be almost in a working state.

Knowing that your structure is `bucket/account_identifier/Patient/patient_identifier`:

```
# account_identifiers -- provided from DB
accounts_df = sc.parallelize(account_identifiers, number_of_partitions)
paths = accounts_df.mapPartitions(fetch_files_for_account).collect()
df = spark.read.json(paths)


def fetch_files_for_account(accounts):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    result = []
    for a in accounts:
        marker = ''
        while True:
            request_result = s3.list_objects(Bucket=args.sourceBucket, Prefix=a)
            items = request_result['Contents']
            for i in items:
                obj_datetime = i['LastModified'].replace(tzinfo=None)
                if obj_datetime > max_previous_data_extracted_timestamp_datetime and obj_datetime <= start_time_datetime:
                    result.append('s3://' + args.sourceBucket +'/' + i['Key'])
            if not request_result['IsTruncated']:
                break
            else:
                marker = request_result['Marker']
    return iter(result)
```

Map partitions will make sure you do not have too many clients instantiated. You can control that number using the `number_of_partitions`.

Another optimisation you can do is to manually load contents after `mapPartitions` call instead of using `collect()`. After that stage you'd have `String`s that are JSON contents and then you'd call `spark.createDataFrame(records, schema)`. Note: you have to provide schema.

If you do not have `account_identifiers` or number of files will not get into 100k territory, you would have to list all object in a bucket, filter by `last_modified` and basically do the same call:

```
spark.read.json(paths)
```

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank you so much Dusan!  I did have to spend some time getting the s3a filesystem up and running so I could ingest the paths, but that wasn't too bad.